# trying to validate an open_api json file with open_api_spec inside a pyinstaller generated executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I use openapi_spec_validator module to validate a json open api file generated by fast api (openapi_spec_validator.validate().

OS: ubuntu 22.04
python version : 3.10.12
openapi_spec_validator : 0.7.1

It works perfectly if I run the application with 'python my_app.py'.
But when I generate the application with pyinstaller and run the onefile executable, I get the following errors:

```
   `024-02-01 12:19:58,200    ERROR __main__ line 55 main No such file:        /tmp/_MEI8wwXvK/openapi_spec_validator/resources/schemas/v3.1/schema.json
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ats_simu_main.py", line 31, in main
  File "ats_simu_manager.py", line 67, in __init__
  File "restManagerDGATS.py", line 11, in __init__
  File "restManager.py", line 52, in __init__
  File "openapi_spec_validator/shortcuts.py", line 48, in validate
  File "openapi_spec_validator/validation/validators.py", line 70, in validate
  File "openapi_spec_validator/validation/caches.py", line 62, in __next__
  File "openapi_spec_validator/validation/caches.py", line 31, in __next__
  File "openapi_spec_validator/validation/decorators.py", line 27, in wrapper
  File "openapi_spec_validator/validation/validators.py", line 89, in iter_errors
  File "<attrs generated init jsonschema.validators.create.<locals>.Validator>", line 7, in __init__
    self.__attrs_post_init__()
  File "jsonschema/validators.py", line 283, in __attrs_post_init__
  File "referencing/_core.py", line 500, in resolver_with_root
  File "referencing/_core.py", line 145, in id
  File "referencing/jsonschema.py", line 37, in _dollar_id
  File "openapi_spec_validator/schemas/utils.py", line 28, in get_schema_content
  File "openapi_spec_validator/schemas/utils.py", line 24, in get_schema
  File "jsonschema_path/readers.py", line 32, in read
   OSError: No such file: /tmp/_MEI8wwXvK/openapi_spec_validator/resources/schemas/v3.1/schema.json
   2024-02-01 12:19:58,200     INFO __main__ line 65 main Server stopped`
```

It seems to be an issue related to openapi_spec_validator and jsonschema but open_api_validator does not provide an api to force the working directory (here /tmp/_MEI8wwXvk where pyinstaller extracts all its stuff to run properly the application).

Any tip ?